# Checking detailed memory information on Linux

Tags: linux, memory

I know that I can check CPU info via `cat /proc/cpuinfo` and memory info via `cat /proc/meminfo`.

But `cat /proc/meminfo` yields results like the following:

```
MemTotal:     66098352 kB
MemFree:        329152 kB
Buffers:        632432 kB
Cached:       62619692 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:        6425444 kB
Inactive:     58717276 kB
SwapTotal:     1951888 kB
SwapFree:      1951796 kB
Dirty:           38416 kB
Writeback:           0 kB
AnonPages:     1890268 kB
Mapped:          12624 kB
Slab:           464580 kB
SReclaimable:   275812 kB
SUnreclaim:     188768 kB
PageTables:       7524 kB
NFS_Unstable:        0 kB
Bounce:              0 kB
CommitLimit:  35001064 kB
Committed_AS:  3860248 kB
VmallocTotal: 34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:    125636 kB
VmallocChunk: 34359612527 kB
HugePages_Total:     0
HugePages_Free:      0
HugePages_Rsvd:      0
HugePages_Surp:      0
Hugepagesize:     2048 kB
```

I want to learn more about the clock speed of the memory (in Mhz?).

How do I get that information?

Answer (score 7):

I think an answer is the dmidecode command :

```
dmidecode -t memory
```

Which output bios informations about memory on your computer.

The outoput is something like :

```
SMBIOS 2.5 present.

Handle 0x1000, DMI type 16, 15 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: Multi-bit ECC
    Maximum Capacity: 8 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 4

Handle 0x1100, DMI type 17, 27 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x1000
    Error Information Handle: No Error
    Total Width: 72 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 1024 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM_1
    Bank Locator: Not Specified
    Type: DDR2
    Type Detail: Synchronous
    Speed: 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
    Manufacturer: AD00000000000000
    Serial Number: XXXXXXXX
    Asset Tag: XXXXXX
    Part Number: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  
...
```

Comment: # dmidecode 2.9
/dev/mem: Permission denied

but I am not root user nor a sudo doer. Do u know any other option?

Comment: Without being able to run a command as root, I don't know how you can found those informations.

Answer (score -1):

you need to be a root user to get information about anything related to system